# Large amount of space underneath footer, bigcommerce

Tags: html, jquery, css, zurb-foundation, bigcommerce

I am having trouble with trying to remove that extra space that is under the footer of this page:
https://www.flexibleassembly.com/rse-test/

When I used the inspection console, I was unable to capture what element is underneath the footer. It only allowed me to get the footer.

I also tried applying `position: sticky; bottom: 0;` and it had the opposite effect of its intended function. It fixed the footer to the top of the page and blocked content.

I also tried jquery that should have set the footer to "fixed" once it passes over the scroll.

I was unsuccessful at locating a script that would forbid anymore scrolling once you scrolled past the footer.

Sorry that this is not as descriptive as it should be. I have no other idea how I can explain it. Simply put, I have no idea where this white space is coming from and I need to remove it - help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Underneath the footer? I can't reproduce that. What I do see is a big space between the form and the footer, See:
https://share.getcloudapp.com/bLue5K6w

Your form's iframe has an inline height value of 710. Changing it to 500 solves it. See:
https://share.getcloudapp.com/p9u7Q6xY